# How to adheres to both the 1.01 and 1.02 versions of the ONVIF standard

Tags: gsoap, onvif, milestone

Milestone documentation mentions that ONVIF cameras must "adheres to both the 1.01 and 1.02 versions of the ONVIF standard".

What does this means in term of implementation with gSOAP ?

Thanks!

Comment: onvif version v1.01, v1.02 is early specification. latest version is 18.12.
since 2016, onvif version release every 6 month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably pointing to obsolete documentation. Nowadays, camera must adhere only to Profiles, such as Profile S or Profile T for cameras.

Adhering to profiles does not pose any particular requirement on gSoap, you need to have updated WSDL file (you can get them from [www.onvif.org](https://www.onvif.org)) and to implement the functions required by each profile.